# Which library I should use to obtain access token?

Tags: python, google-signin

I have a web page with Google Sign-In and I want to access user's data on behalf of the user even if he is offline.

I am looking for a suggestion for a library that I can use to obtain `access token` and `refresh token` using the `authorization code` that the client sent to the server.

I followed the official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).
In *Step 7: Exchange the authorization code for an access token*, the author uses [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) library which appears to be deprecated:

> Note: oauth2client is now deprecated. No more features will be added to the libraries and the core team is turning down support. We recommend you use google-auth and oauthlib. For more details on the deprecation, see oauth2client deprecation.

So I looked at [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> This library provides no support for obtaining user credentials, but does provide limited support for using user credentials.

I also took a look at [oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/clients/client.html), but there are many pages undocumented.

I am using Python 3.x with Flask.

Comment: I really don't understand why I am getting downvoted, care someone give a reason or a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Ended using [Requests-OAuthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib).

`pip install requests requests_oauthlib`

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                      scope=GOOGLE_SCOPE,
                      redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000')

token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL,
                          code=authorization_code,
                          client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
```